# How to set a template programmatically using a plugin

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.2

How can I change the template set in back-end with a custom plugin?

I was different solutions suggesting using

```
$doc= JFactory::getDocument();
$doc->setTemplate("my_tempalte_name");
```

which did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Joomla 3.2. + you can make use of the `JApplicationSite::setTemplate` method.

You need to put this in a system plugin which triggers on `onAfterInitialise`.

```
public function onAfterInitialise()
{
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    // We want to change the template just on the FE
    if ($app instanceof JApplicationSite)
    {
        $template = $app->getTemplate(); //use just debugging
        var_dump($template); //use just debugging
        // Set the new template and style params
        $app->setTemplate('protostar', null);
        $template = $app->getTemplate(); //use just debugging
        var_dump($template); //use just debugging
    }

}
```

The signature `JApplicationSite::setTemplate` of is:

```
/**
 * Overrides the default template that would be used
 *
 * @param   string  $template     The template name
 * @param   mixed   $styleParams  The template style parameters
 *
 * @return  void
 *
 * @since   3.2
 */
public function setTemplate($template, $styleParams = null)
```

Comment: This method used to also work within component code such as views and controllers in Joomla 1.5. I've just discovered it no longer works there for J3.2, but only in the system plugin as you've described above, which is proving frustrating. Any idea why this changed? The component code executes before the template is rendered anyway, so this seems unnecessarily restrictive.

Comment: The code-base has changed a lot since 1.5, for the  better I would add. While some changes don't necessary make sense at the first glance, there are generally caused by the need of a better software architecture. Anyway, I do feel as well that changing the template from the component should work as well (maybe there is a bug there). Feel free to send a bug report or to have a closer look at the code and to submit a patch - Joomla is open source and ANYONE can get involved in making it better.